# Load control throws The calling thread cannot access this object...

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I have to load a XAML file, but since it function only in context of a STA thread, I have to start a new thread and set the apartment state of it to STA.

After control is loaded I want to get all its logical children with LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren( ... ).

At that point I get System.InvalidOperationException with the Message=The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

The code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Thread STAThread = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// XAML path.
    /// </summary>
    private static string _selectedXAML = Path.GetFullPath( @"..\..\Resources\UserControl1.xaml" );

    private FrameworkElement _loadedUI = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        this.LoadUI();
        DependencyObject depObj = _loadedUI as DependencyObject;

        var s = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren( depObj );
    }

    private void LoadUI()
    {
        // Read the text as string from the file
        var xamlText = File.ReadAllText( _selectedXAML );

        // Replace variable values and script value pairs
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader( xamlText );
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create( stringReader );

        STAThread = new Thread(
            () =>
            {
                _loadedUI = XamlReader.Load( xmlReader ) as FrameworkElement;
            } );


        STAThread.SetApartmentState( ApartmentState.STA );

        STAThread.Start();

        STAThread.Join();
    }
}
```

**So how can I change the object’s thread owner?**

Tying to invoke any of Dispatcher's "Invoke" methods on window object don't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the owning thread. Instead you may simplify your `LoadUI` method.

Drop all the separate thread stuff and load the XAML directly, as the `Join` call would block your UI thread anyway until the load thread has finished.

```
private FrameworkElement LoadUI()
{
    // Read the text as string from the file
    var xamlText = File.ReadAllText(_selectedXAML);

    // Replace variable values and script value pairs
    var stringReader = new StringReader(xamlText);
    var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

    return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as FrameworkElement;
}

private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var s = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(LoadUI());
}
```